# Python catching exceptions and payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have the following Python Project

.\Mainfunction.py

.\Modules\DatabaseFunction.py

.\Modules\DataBaseConnection.py

Now at the DataBaseConnection.py I am raising an exception :-

```
except pymysql.Error as ex:
  raise json.dumps('error payload')
```

This goes up a level to DatabaseFunction.py which is correct at this point I am not catching this error as I want it to filter to Mainfunction.py. My question is how do I catch this expcetion and payload at this level?

I have been messing around with the following most of the day which is miles off :-

```py
try:
    x = DatabaseFunction.function(value1, value2, value3, etc)
except:
    print(x)
    pass
```

I am basically trying to pass up any caught errors to the highest level and handle them at them at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a custom Exception for that scenario

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errors=None):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.errors = errors
```

so in your code you can implement something like:

```
except pymysql.Error as ex:
  raise CustomError('error payload')
```

And the catch:

```
try:
  x = DatabaseFunction.function(value1, value2, value3, etc)
except CustomError as e
  print(e.message)
```